# docker for windows & mysql official container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm running MySQL inside the latest official MySQL docker container. 
The host machine is Windows 10.

I'm using "docker-compose up mysql" to start the following service:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    container_name: sqlstore
    ports:
     - '3306:3306'
    expose:
     - '3306'
    env_file:
     - ./sqlconfig.env  
    volumes:
     - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

The problem that I'm having is when MySQL database files reside on the host's volume, MySQL fails to run and I keep getting the following error message:
"do you already have another mysqld server running on the socket: "/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock""

It is worth noting that I did make sure that the port is not being used by other processes, and MySQL's files are indeed being written to the ./data directory on the host.

However, when the MySQL files do not reside on the host but inside the docker itself, everything runs correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. If you're on Linux container, the issue is very likely related to different file-system type that the MySQL container has and the Windows host machine. Using named volumes i.e. `some-data:/var/lib/mysql` might resolve the issue. Working example:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    container_name: sqlstore
    ports:
     - '3306:3306'
    expose:
     - '3306'
    env_file:
     - ./sqlconfig.env
    volumes:
     - datavol:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  datavol:
```

Comment: actually, I did try to go this route, however, I kept getting ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.volumes: 'datavol'


  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    container_name: sqlstore
    env_file:
      - ./sqlconfig.env  
    volumes:
      - datavol:/var/lib/mysql
  volumes:
    datavol:

Comment: Working example added.